# jQuery .filter is working with .css(display) but not with .css(background-color)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

I have an issue where .filter() works with `.css('display')` but not `.css('background-color')`.

Below is the code that doesn't work (i.e. `highlighted.length = 0`):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){

 var keyCode = e.keyCode;
 var $listUnit = $(".list-unit");

 var listKeyCode = $listUnit.filter(function() {
     return $(this).text() == keyCode;
 });

 listKeyCode.css('background-color','blue');

 var highlighted = $listUnit.filter(function(){
     return  $(this).css('background-color') == 'blue';
 });

 console.log('highlighted',highlighted.length);
 }

});
```

The code that does work (i.e. `highlighted.length > 0)`:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){

 var keyCode = e.keyCode;
 var $listUnit = $(".list-unit");

 var listKeyCode = $listUnit.filter(function() {
     return $(this).text() == keyCode;
 });

 listKeyCode.css('display','none');

 var highlighted = $listUnit.filter(function(){
     return  $(this).css('display') == 'none';
 });

 console.log('highlighted',highlighted.length);
 }

});
```

Explanation:

On keydown, my code selects the element with class `.list-unit` whose text value is equal to the key code of the keydown event, and then changes its background color to blue. The code then filters all the `.list-unit` elements with `background-color: blue` and returns that value to the variable `highlighted`.

The `highlighted` variable, however, gives `length = 0` when logged to the console. But if instead of selecting for `background-color`, I select for `display` (i.e. replacing all `.css('background-color','x')` with `.css('display','x')`, the `highlighted` variable contains the correct length.

I've tried replacing `background-color` with `backgroundColor` and using `rgb(x,x,x)` instead of `"blue"` - to no avail.

Comment: what results you get then you console.log( $(this).css('background-color') ); i think it will help us to answer your question.

Comment: $(this).css('background-color') = 'blue'. This is also reflected on the site - the selected div's background color changes to blue. It is also reflected in the HTML, which shows an inline style change (to background-color = blue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
var highlighted = $listUnit.filter(function(){ 
  return  $(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(0,0,255)';
});
```

instead of:

```
var highlighted = $listUnit.filter(function(){
  return  $(this).css('background-color') == 'blue';
});
```

Even though the HTML showed `style = "background-color: blue"`, I had to use `$(this).css('background-color') == rgb(0,0,255)` to select correctly for blue.